# Android disable button with case differentiation

Tags: android, button

So I really have no clue why this isn't wokring - basic stuff I did hundred times before:

I want to disable the button 'loadGame' by doing the following if the boolean is false:

```
if(saveExists == false){
        loadGame.setEnabled(false);
    }else{
        loadGame.setEnabled(true);
    }
```

saveExists is a boolean taken from a sharedPreferences object which is by default false (works, because I already checked saveExists in an output line).
Basically no matter what cases I create with if/elseif/else the button doesn't seem to get disabled at any point - did I really miss something big?

---

Okay so here's some code concerning the SharedPreference:

```
SharedPreferences settings;
SharedPreferences.Editor preferenceEditor;
```

...

In the onCreate of the class where I want to disable the button:

```
Resource.settings = getSharedPreferences(Resource.PREFERENCE_AUDIO, MODE_PRIVATE);
    Resource.preferenceEditor = Resource.settings.edit();
    saveExists = Resource.settings.getBoolean("settings", false);
    Log.d(TAG, "saveExists="+saveExists);
```

and finally, the part to disable the Button:

```
loadGame = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.loadButton);
    loadGame.setEnabled(saveExists);
    loadGame.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {...}
```

Oh btw we're talking about a ImageButton here

**SOLUTION: You won't see this coming**

God I hate to break it to you but that was clearly my fault. My projectpartner toggled the buttons invisible/visible as part of the AsyncTask and it's executed after I'm doing what I tried here all the time - yup shame on me I guess :x

Comment: try to log wherever you changes button's setEnabled in whole activity...you might track the problem!

Comment: thing is, this is the one and only time the button is enabled/disabled

Comment: then check your SharedPreference object for both "true" and "false" cases,whether it is containing the proper value for the times. and also check,did you commit() where you changed SharedPreference Object..

Comment: every change is being commited afterwards, already checked that

Comment: And you are getting 'true' and 'false' in log for cases,perfectly??

Comment: I'm currently working with just false for the toggle line, if my boolean is saved and used correctly is atm a minor problem to me. Look at my comments on the other answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very hard to determine the problem without more information.  If the is/elseif/else doesn't seem to be working, you can try modifying your code to this to see what's going on:

```
if(saveExists == false){
    Log.v("TEST", "saveExists is false");
}else{
    Log.v("TEST", "saveExists is true");
}
```

If that is working then the problem seems to be with disabling the button.  Does execution this line without the if/else work?

```
loadGame.setEnabled(false);
```

---

**EDIT**

From your update, I see you're using an ImageButton.  For disabling an ImageButton, use `setClickable(saveExists)`

Comment: oh yeah : loadGame.setEnabled(false); doesn't have any effect. Not sure what wrong there

Comment: @Rickyfox are you sure this code is executing?  Can you put a log statement right next to it and verify that your message shows up in logcat?

Comment: Log.d(TAG, "vor setEnabled");
  loadGame.setEnabled(false);
  Log.d(TAG, "nach setEnabled");

both lines appear in the logs - yet the button is still active. I'm so mad right now I can tell ya

Comment: @Rickyfox ImageButtons use `setClickable(boolean)` instead.  Try that.

Comment: Nope the button is still clickable, I just replaced .setEnabled(false) with .setClickable(false)

Comment: @Rickyfox I'm not sure of the problem without seeing more of the code.  However, another possibility you have is to check `saveExists` during your handling of the onClick event.

Comment: Thx for your interest and help with this problem, I posted the solution. Sry for wasting your time in such a way :/

Answer (score 1):

why don't use saveExist itself into the argument no need to used if/else

```
loadGame.setEnabled(saveExists);
```

if it is true then it is enabled otherwise not